# c# input string was not in a correct format (how to deal with corrupted data?)

Tags: c#, string, search

I am creating a windows form that searches 3 files sequentially by using String.Compare.  if text box is not empty it will first search by text box string, if it is empty it will then search by company string.  the file which contains numbers have some "corrupted" lines ex. 1345.2fd I am suppose to deal with these by making them to come out as "Sales Figure corrupted" which I though I did, but when I run the program I get input string error.

The line is 42

```
salesData = decimal.Parse(salesFile.ReadLine().Trim());
```

Comment: On which line throws this?

Comment: sorry my mistake: its line 42 salesData = decimal.Parse(salesFile.ReadLine().Trim());

Comment: Use TryParse. You file data is not in correct format. (May be have “,” instead of “.” ? for decimal separator)

Comment: Instead of `decimal.Parse` use `decimal.TryParse`

Comment: This `fd` part is always there? Is there any possible to get another characters?

Comment: yes, there are 2 corrupted lines which are meant to be like that, I am suppose to make them come out as "sales data corrupted" but it is not working

Comment: @Maximilious Is my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `salesFile.ReadLine()` is null.

```
decimal salesData = 0;
string s = salesFile.ReadLine();
if (s != null && decimal.TryParse(s.Trim(), out salesData))
{
    // True
}
else
{
    //Your data is error
}
```

also: this also can make the error, because you dont check for null:

```
gamesData = gamesFile.ReadLine().Trim();  // <---- May cause Error
salesData = decimal.Parse(salesFile.ReadLine().Trim());  // <---- May cause Error
compData = compFile.ReadLine().Trim();  // <---- May cause Error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is FormatException triggered by decimal.Parse() function. The function excepts a number but your malformed strings are not a true number, so exception is thrown. You better use a try-catch and handle the error
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z(v=vs.110).aspx